# WindowsLookAndFeel - What font is used - Is there a way to change it

Tags: swing, uimanager

UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");

What font gets used? If I have an app, which is using the windowslookandfeel, is there a way to change the font used on a local system, by changing the default font for this L&F - I am looking at changing Windows options - such as Control Panel/Registry/System Properties etc..

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Multiple default fonts are used in the Windows L&F. The most used one is `Font.DIALOG`, but it also uses `Font.SANS_SERIF`, and `Font.MONOSPACED`. Changing the default is done via the class UIDefaults ([JavaDoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/UIDefaults.html)).